# Testing nested function in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I want make a testing in my project and the function I want test is a nested function, there function in function

the function like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMenu()
  }
```

this is my test spec:

```
    describe('NavigationComponent', () => {
        let component: NavigationComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavigationComponent>;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [

            ],
            providers: [
              { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService }
            ]
          })
          .compileComponents();
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationComponent);
          //navComponent = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
          fixture.detectChanges();
        });

  it('getMenu should called', ()=>{
        spyOn(component, 'getMenu');                  
        fixture.detectChanges();                      
        expect(component.getMenu).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

It's work when I test ngOnInit, but I don't know how to test "getMenu"

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the method `getMenu()` was called or not when `ngOnInit()` ran.

What you have to do is spy on that method and then verify.

```
spyOn(compInstance, 'getMenu');                  //spy on getMenu
fixture.detectChanges();                         //calls ngOnInit() and updates dom
expect(compInstance.getMenu).toHaveBeenCalled(); //verify getMenu() invokation
```

If you want to test the logic of `getMenu()`, then you can directly call it from your test spec and then verify its output.

```
let res = compInstance.getMenu();
expect(res).toBe('pizza');
```

Comment: I try it and I get this message
<spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for getMenu()
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)

Comment: Can you please show your test spec? Better add that to your question.

Comment: I add my test spec

Comment: Comment out `fixture.detectChanges()` inside before each and check. Because when first detectChanges happens ngOnInit() gets called. So before spying, `getMenu()` will be called. To avoid this, you have to spy on any method before it is being called.

Comment: after I comment I still get that message:
<spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for getMenu()
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)

Answer (score -1):

Add spyOn(component, 'getMenu'); in beforeEach block after you are assigning component variable.

The error is telling you that it is not getting the required method that you want to spy on.

PS- Too late for this answer, but maybe it will help someone else

Comment: That would not solve the issue - it would just test that the function was called, but not actually test the function itself

Comment: you can chain it with .and.callThrough() if you want to call the real function